# $prepStatement->execute(array_values($inv)); does not work

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo, execute

i can't find the solution. 
$prepStatement->execute(array_values($inv)); does not work 
I got an error at this line.

my php script:

```
<?php

$response=array();
$json = $_REQUEST['json'];
$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump(json_decode($json, true));

print "Starting request". "<br/>";
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE))
{   

    if($data->connection && $data->wykazy)
    {
        print "connection and wykazy exist". "<br/>";
        if ($data->connection->Host && $data->connection->db && $data->connection->User && $data->connection->password) {
            print "connection Host, db, User, password are OK". "<br/>";
            try
            {
                $opt = [
                        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                        ];
                $dbObj = new PDO('mysql:host='.$data->connection->Host.';dbname='.$data->connection->db, $data->connection->User, $data->connection->password, $opt);
                print "Proba ustanowienia polaczenia! Bledy: " . $dbObj->errorCode() . "<br/>";
                createWykaz($dbObj, $data);
            }
            catch (PDOException $e)
            {
                print "Blad podczas tworzeniu obiektu dbObj!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
                $response["success"]=0;
                $response["message"]="Can not connect to database!: " . $e->getMessage();
                echo json_encode($response);
                die();
            }
            //$mysqli = new mysqli($data->connection->Host, $data->connection->User, $data->connection->password, $data->connection->db);

        }
    }
    else 
    {
        print "connection i wykazy nie istnieją! " . "<br/>";
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="Error: Required fields are missing!";
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}

function createWykaz($dbObj, $data)
{
    try{    
        $allowedVariables = array(
                'wyk_ilosc',
                'wyk_czasod',
                'wyk_czasdo',
                'wyk_id_czynnosc',
                'wyk_id_pracownik',
                'wyk_id_partia',
                'wyk_status',
        );

        $sql = "insert into wykaz (". implode(',', $allowedVariables) .")";
        $sql.= " VALUES (". substr(str_repeat('?,', sizeof($allowedVariables)), 0, -1) .");";
        print "sql: ". $sql . "<br/>";
        if($prepStatement = $dbObj->prepare($sql)){
            //edit

            $dbObj->beginTransaction();


            foreach ( $data->wykazy as $inv ) {
                $res = $prepStatement->execute(array_values($inv));
            }
        /*
            $prepStatement = $dbObj->prepare($sql)
            foreach ($data->wykazy as $row) {
            $dbObj->executeMultiple($prepStatement, $row);//return DB_OK
         }
         */

            $response["success"]=1;
            $response["message"]="Wszystkie wykazy successfully added to Database!";
            echo json_encode($response);

            $dbObj->commit();

        }
        else {
            $response["success"]=0;
            $response["message"]="Błąd podczas przygotowania zapytania!"+ $prepStatement;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
        $dbObj=null;
        $prepStatement=null;

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        //Error handling goes here
        echo "Sorry, the website is experiencing problems.";
        echo "Error: Our query failed to execute and here is why: \n";
        echo "Query: " . $sql . "\n";
        echo "Errno: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        $response["success"]=0;
        $response["message"]="Our query failed to execute!". $e->getMessage();
        echo json_encode($response);
        $dbObj=null;
        $prepStatement=null;
    }

}

?>
```

it works till:
$prepStatement->execute(array_values($inv)); 
I am getting an error at this position, but $data->wykazy is an array.

I can change my code to:

```
$sth = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
foreach ($alldata as $row) {
    $db->execute($sth, $row);
}
```

but I will try the other way.
Thanks for help
Sebastian

The output from Postman:

[Postman part1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3i49U.jpg)
[Postman part2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtBut.jpg)

Comment: **What error** It would be nice if we did not have to guess!

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Comment: sorry it is under the link Postman part2 ( ! ) Warning: PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given in D:\wamp64\www\insertAllWykaz.php on line 188

Comment: You are running One execute for each parameter! You need to build one array containing all the parameters and run execute ONCE

Comment: You mean something like this, or am I wrong?   foreach($data->wykazy as $inv){
    $array = array($inv->wyk_ilosc, $inv->wyk_czasod, $inv->wyk_czasdo,...);
    $res = $prepStatement->execute($array);

Comment: Thanks, You were right it is working now. Thanks a lot ;-) The solution is: foreach ( $data->wykazy as $inv ) {
     $array = array($inv->wyk_ilosc, $inv->wyk_czasod, $inv->wyk_czasdo, $inv->wyk_id_czynnosc, $inv->wyk_id_pracownik, $inv->wyk_id_partia, $inv->wyk_status);
     $res = $prepStatement->execute(array_values($array));
    }